# NHibernate HiLo algorithm re-using hi as lo?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm using NHibernate 3.1 with FluentNHibernate 1.2.0.712.

We're using the HiLo generator to generate Ids - with standard settings except max_lo is set to 100 (default 1000).

Our mappings all have this line in the ctor:

```
Id(m => m.Id)
    .GeneratedBy.HiLo("100");
```

Hovewer, when we start fresh with a new SessionFactory, and the first item is saved - let's say the next hi is 12 it gets Id 1212 (I would have expected 1200 or 1201). Is this intended behaviour or am I missing some vital part of the configuration?

I've tried using default values ("1000") as the max_lo, but then the above would result in 12012 - still not exactly what I would expect.

Comment: Are you sure you are saving only one entity?

Comment: Yes. I have NH profiler running and is looking at the database continously as well as stepping through code. If I try to save another type of entity afterwards - it gets Id: 1313. Subsequent entities get 1213 and 1314 as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read through the nhibernate code-base. This is apparently intended behaviour - for the initial set, it 'clocks over' (for a reason beyond me - but probably has something to do with keeping parity with hibernate (since that has that exact same comment :-)).

For all subsequent increments - all is performing as expected.

So, closing down this question.